# Problems using count() in boolean indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of the form (but with many more rows):

```
Type          Thing
adfh+daw      (d,y,u)
daadad++S     (d,a)
```

I only want to keep the rows where the number of + in Type is equal to the number of elements in Thing. I tried to do this using the following boolean indexing:

```
print(data[data["Type"].count('+') != len(data["Thing"].split(","))].head())
```

This gives the error `KeyError: 'Level + must be same as name (None)`
However, if I just take the first row and do the same operations separately like this it works:

```
print(data.iloc[0]["Type"].count("+"))
print(len(data.iloc[0]["Thing"].split(",")))
```

Is there a problem with using the count() function in boolean indexing?

Comment: you're using the pandas count method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html, not the string count method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.count` to count the `+` and `str.split` with `str.len` to get the amount of elements after splitting on `,`:

*note*: we are using `\+` since the backlash is an escape character to match actual `+` since the vanilla plus sign means `one or more` in regex.

```
plusses = df['Type'].str.count('\+')
elements = df['Thing'].str.split(',').str.len()

df = df.loc[plusses.eq(elements)]

        Type  Thing
1  daadad++S  (d,a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `'+'`, since it is a special character. Also for counting the length of the tuples I'd use the following:

```
tuple_len = df.Thing.str.count(',').add(1)
df.loc[df['Type'].str.count('\+').eq(tuple_len),:]

     Type    Thing
1  daadad++S  (d,a)
```